# easiest way to collect emails from a website?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, integration, form

I want a simple form with just a field to collect email on a joomla site. What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @new-to-et, you've reached Salesforce Stack Exchange. Your question is better suited to Stack Overflow or a Joomla-specific forum; we only cover Salesforce and its associated technologies.

Comment: sorry for not specifying that emails collected would go to a list in exacttarget.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is either Web Collect or DE Manager, depending on if you indeed want to add emails to lists or to Data Extensions. They are both well described in [this documentation article.](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/)

If this is a brand new setup, I will in most cases go with DE Manager, and work around that. Data Extensions have clear advantages over lists, which you can [read about here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_list_versus_data_extension.htm&type=5), with some clear pros and cons of both approaches.

Best regards - Lukas